# JavaEE 7/JAX-RS: does the standard define when exactly a database commit happens?

Tags: java, jpa, jax-rs, java-ee-7, jta

I'm using a JDBC DataSource managed by WildFly 11 and used via JPA 2.1. I have annotated JAX-RS resource methods with @Transactional. When exactly do transactions get committed in relation to sending back the response to the remote client? I'm asking this for an obious reason: can clients stall transactions and perform a database DoS when sending back larger amounts of data?